# How to execute Assembly code starting at a particular address?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I just started learning basic Assembly in Computer Architecture class and coding using emu8086. I'm required to execute the code starting at a particular address. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: Use the `ORG` directive?

Comment: `ORG` will just set address where the following source will assemble to. Where the starts depends how you execute it. In emu8086 most of the early examples tend to be "COM" files, which are loaded into memory from offset 100h, and executed from the first instruction (at that address 100h) and you can't do anything about it (except putting there as your first instruction for example `org 100h` `jmp realStart` to jump to other address). With "EXE" executables you can actually set up the desired entry point to the code, which is executed first after the OS loads the code into memory.

Comment: I.e. it's not obvious what you are asking, I think `ORG` probably *is* what you need to learn about, but maybe you are really asking about how to *execute* the code, then it depends what OS and executable format you are targetting (OS under emu8086 is [fake] DOS of course, so the options are only COM or EXE). But to execute some code you need first to assemble it in a way "as if at that address" - `org` helps with that => that goes into executable file => that is loaded into memory + executed (even if it's one click, try to have some idea what each step does, so you get the principle of it)

Comment: @Ped7g: Probably taking the same class as the user that posted this much more detailed question: [8086 can't access to external memory](//stackoverflow.com/q/58643424).  Should probably close as a duplicate if that gets answered, because an answer saying "load your code there and far jmp" is about all that's possible here.